# Using Take() to grab bytes out of a byte array, having trouble converting back to byte[] after the Take()

Tags: c#, take

```
byte[] result = memStream.ToArray();                              
memStream.Close();
byte[] temp = result.Take(255);
var str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(temp);
```

The above fails on the `result.Take(255);` line. It says I can't convert `IEnumerable` to `byte[]`, and asks if I'm missing a cast.

I'm new to C#, not exactly sure what to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Take()` returns an enumerator object that executes when you enumerate it:

[image]

That's not an array, so you can't assign it to a reference to a byte array. However, with LINQ, you can take any sequence and *convert* it to an array of the appropriate type by calling its `ToArray()` method:

```
byte[] temp = result.Take(255).ToArray();
```

`ToArray()` enumerates the result from `Take(255)`, puts the results in a new array, and returns the array.

It's a little confusing because you can enumerate an array just like you can enumerate the thing you get from `Take(255)` -- but you can enumerate a lot of things. That's just one behavior they have in common, but they're actually very different objects.

You could assign either one to `IEnumerable<byte>`:

```
IEnumerable<byte> a = result.Take(255);
IEnumerable<byte> b = result.Take(255).ToArray();
```

...because that's one thing they really have in common.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Could you explain why yours works and mine doesn't?

Comment: @MrDysprosium I'll update my answer with a little more detail.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code is giving an error is because `.Take(result)` returns an `IEnumerable<byte>` type and you're trying to assign it to a `byte[]` array. `.Take()` is a [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693024.aspx) method and this is typically the way all LINQ methods work for the purpose of chaining (e.g. result.Skip(5).Take(10)).

The `.ToArray()` method takes an `IEnumerable<T>` result and turns it into a `T[]`. So adding `.ToArray()` to your line will fix your problem:

```
byte[] temp = result.Take(255).ToArray();
```

Instead of using `.Take()` and then creating another array, you'll probably find this more performant:

```
byte[] temp = new byte[255]
Array.Copy(result, temp, 255);
```

The reason is because `.ToArray()` has no idea how big the resulting array will need to be, so it has to just pick some relatively small size and as more items get read in, it has to resize to expand capacity. This can occur dozens of times, depending on the number of items, before the array is large enough to store all of the items.